# numpy arange values are changing signs unexpectedly

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am teaching mysef a little about `numpy` and I have dusted off some of my old undergraduate texts to use for examples.  So, I wrote a function *without* `numpy` to calculate the deflection in a cantilever beam due to a single point load at any point.  Pretty straight forward, except that the deflection equation changes depending on what side of the point force you are on, so I will split the beam into two ranges, calculate the deflection values at each interval in the ranges and append the result to a list.  Here's the code.

```
def deflection(l, P, a, E, I):
    """
    Calculate the deflection of a cantilever beam due to a simple point load.

    Calculates the deflection at equal one inch intervals along the beam and
    returns the deflection as a list along with the the length range.

    Parameters
    ----------
    l : float
        beam length (in)
    P : float
        Point Force (lbs)
    a : float
        distance from fixed end to force (in)
    E : float
        modulus of elasticity (psi)
    I : float
        moment of inertia (in**4)

    Returns
    -------
    list
        x : distance along beam (in)

    list of floats
        y : deflection of beam (in)

    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        If a < 0 or a > l (denoting force location is off the beam)
    """
    if (a < 0) or (a > l):
        raise ValueError('force location is off beam')

    x1 = range(0, a)
    x2 = range(a, l + 1)
    deflects = []
    for x in x1:
        y = (3 * a - x) * (P * x**2) / (6 * E * I)
        deflects.append(y)
    for x in x2:
        y = (3 * x - a) * (P * a**2) / (6 * E * I)
        deflects.append(y)
    return list(x1) + list(x2), deflects
```

Now I want to do the same thing using numpy, so I wrote the following function:

```
def np_deflection(l, P, a, E, I):
    """To Do.  Write me."""
    if (a < 0) or (a > l):
        raise ValueError('force location is off beam')
    x1 = np.arange(0, a)
    x2 = np.arange(a, l + 1)
    y1 = (3 * a - x1) * (P * x1**2) / (6 * E * I)
    y2 = (3 * x2 - a) * (P * a**2) / (6 * E * I)
    return np.hstack([x1, x2]), np.hstack([y1, y2])
```

Here's the issue, at some point in the calculations, the value of y1 changes sign.  Here's an example.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l, P, a, E, I = 120, 1200, 100, 30000000, 926

x, y = deflection(l, P, a, E, I)
print(max(y))

np_x, np_y = np_deflection(l, P, a, E, I)
print(max(np_y))

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(x, y, 'b.-')
plt.xlabel('dist from fixed end (in)')
plt.ylabel('using a range/list')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(np_x, np_y, 'r.-')
plt.xlabel('dist from fixed end (in)')
plt.ylabel('using numpy range')

plt.show()
```

If you run the plot, you'll see that at point `x = 93` which is in `x1`, there is a dislocation in the curve where the value seems to change sign.
[image: plot of results]
Can anyone explain a) what is happening? and b) what I did wrong?

Comment: Watch out for overflow. The parameters you say are floats are actually ints, and Python ints have very different overflow behavior from NumPy ints.

Comment: @user2357112: you are right!  I changed my input callout to `l, P, a, E, I = 120.00, 1200.00, 100.00, 30000000.00, 926.00` (which also meant I had to cast the `a` and `l` as integers in my non-numpy range definitions) and the dislocation was fixed.

Comment: @user2357112, what would be the proper/preferred way to protect the numpy function from this overflow? Obviously if a user can input `100` vs `100.0` they will.  Do I recast the inputs as they come into the function?  or do I change the `dtype` to `int64` or something else?

Comment: I'd probably use float constants instead of ints inside the function, specify an appropriate dtype for the aranges, and cast the inputs to floats with `l, P, a, E, I = map(float, [l, P, a, E, I])`.

Comment: can somebody post an explanation of the difference between python and numpy with regard to int overflow behavior?  (@user2357112?)

Comment: @dbliss Python uses an "unlimited" int type, whereas numpy uses very specific #bit types. Consequently, it's much harder to overflow a Python int, and it's relatively easy to make a mistake when translating Python ints to numpy ints (not the other way around).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting this has nothing to do with overflow as some folks have suggested and everything to do with the default `dtype` for `np.arange`.  If you pass in an integer start, stop, and step to `arange`, then the output will be an integer array.

In python 2.x, the `/` operator uses integer division.

---

For example:

```
import numpy as np

print np.arange(10) / 3
```

Results in:

```
[0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3]
```

---

However,

```
np.arange(10, dtype=float) / 3
```

or

```
np.arange(10.0) / 3
```

or

```
np.arange(10) / 3.0
```

Will all result in

```
[ 0.          0.33333333  0.66666667  1.          1.33333333  1.66666667
  2.          2.33333333  2.66666667  3.        ]
```

---

If you'd prefer that the `/` operator always upcast the results to floating point, then you can use `from __future__ import division`.

An alternative option is to be aware of the data type of your arrays.  Numpy lets you have very low-level control over how the data is stored in memory.  This is *very*, *very* useful in practice, but it may seem a bit surprising at first.  However, the upcasting rules are quite simple and well worth being aware of.  Basically, whenever two types are used in an operation, if they're the same, the type is preserved. Otherwise, the more general of the two is used.

Comment: Note the Python 3 tag. Trying the OP's code on Python 3 produces exactly the OP's described results; trying it with Python 2 division rules produces very different output.

Comment: @user2357112, you are correct.  The results presented are from Python 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

Try using numpy.arange(..., dtype=numpy.double) or cast the result with astype(np.double)

There might be some subtle between the two - akin to a for loop with floats, erring on the side of caution/habbit I would say astype is a better habbit.

Comment: Actually, if you mix a float scalar and an int ndarray together, the output is always a float.  Numpy types aren't somehow more "sticky" than builtin types.  Numpy deliberately follows the same conventions python does in that regard, it just has more numeric types (e.g. `uint8`, `float16`, etc).

Comment: @JoeKington you are right, could've sworn I've been bitten by this before back in 2008 or so though.